# Intellij IDEA: multiple goals, multiple projects, one button

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

I find myself often running the same goals (clean install) of different, interdependent maven projects in Intellij IDEA one after another.

Does anyone know of a way to configure something like a maven goal combination, ideally such that you configure a button in IDEA's task bar that you can hit to execute these goals in sequence?  Possibly even with a keyboard short cut?

Similar things might be achieved with a maven run configuration, but then IDEA wouldn't automatically be aware of the changes the run does to the project's file system resources.

Cheers,
Johannes

Answer (score 8):

Easy solution for me was to create a Run Configuration (type=Maven) per module, putting multiple goals (e.g: clean install) as cmd line for each of them, then linking them up into a chain, by adding an appropriate one under the "Before launch" section.

You can link up the last of the chain as a "Before launch" for the actual app Run.
Then you can, if required, just restart a running instance if your app which will rebuild your maven projects in order, and start the app again.

Comment: One thing to clarify - in the Before Launch section, don't choose "Run Maven Goal", choose "Run Another Configuration" and then from that list, choose the Maven Run Configuration that you want to run prior to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently run a clean install of my maven aggregator project from the command line while it is open in IntelliJ. In my experience the IDE seems to handle this quite well.

Comment: I do that, too, but my clean build includes a Jaxb run over a couple of xsds.  That means that a lot of Java classes (appear to) change and Intellij has to re-index them all.

Answer (score 0):

when you open the MVN - 'Run Anything' appears - beside that there is a PROJECT drop down, from which you can select for which project you want to run  the maven command.